# Shocked, content of my webroot on localhost could be seen on www

Tags: apache2, dns, firewall, localhost

I am new to this forum, and in doubt where to ask this question, so please guide me if this is not the place to ask.

Well, I got shocked today, I realised that the content of my /var/www/html folder were accesible from www on the domain olsenweb .dk - without java script enabled in my browser. I have installed AMP server on my desktop and use it from my desktop. Previously I have used it from another devise on my network, then I can not use localhost but have to reconfigure apace and change it to my IP address, e.g. 192.168.1.10. Anyway I was sure that I had to do something actively to publish the content to www.

I especially do not understand what is happening, I can not access it from another device if Apace is configuret to localhost, but I can access the content from a remote web page on www? Is it my router/firewall I should be concerned about? Unfortunately I know very little about network, firewalls and apache.

Edit:
I can see now that my localhost content is shown in a frame:

```
    <frameset cols="100%">
    <frame name="gratisdns" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" framepadding="0" 
src="http://joltestserver.cloudapp.net">
    </frameset>
```

So it might not be accessible from www but only for me, could it be only 'localhost' that is changed to 'joltestserver.cloudapp.net' in my browser? olsenweb apparently is hosted on joltestserver.cloudapp.net

edit 2:

```
ping joltestserver.cloudapp.net
```

PING joltestserver.cloudapp.net (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms
...

edit 3:

I have added a DNS tag - wondring if it could be a misconfigured DNS for joltestserver.cloudapp.net combined with a redirect from olsenweb?

Comment: I find your post quite hard to follow, but  /var/www/html is the (default) place you put files to allow Apache to serve them. Perhaps that will help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: I know. My question is how it can be shown to me on the URL joltestserver.cloudapp.net

Comment: Maybe you need to check your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: @muru My hosts file points to my device: 127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mypc

Comment: What does `dig joltestserver.cloudapp.net` report?

Comment: `; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.9-Ubuntu <<>> joltestserver.cloudapp.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39428
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;joltestserver.cloudapp.net. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
joltestserver.cloudapp.net. 60 IN A 0.0.0.0

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 31 11:15:58 CET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
`

Comment: olsenweb .dk's IP: 91.221.196.253, which is a Danish DNS service server. Accessing it gives you an  URL forward error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, `joltestserver.cloudapp.net` resolves to `0.0.0.0`:

```
DNS server handling your query: 8.8.8.8
DNS server's address:   8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   joltestserver.cloudapp.net
Address: 0.0.0.0
```

`0.0.0.0` is a special address with a special meaning - and if you try to connect to it, Ubuntu treats it as `127.0.0.1` == `localhost` or "this machine".

(Why they'd want to have their DNS entry set to `0.0.0.0` I don't know.)

Comment: Thank you. So I am more calm. At first sight I thought that my pc was accessible from the web. I do not fully understand your answer, but it seems to mean that I was right to suspecting the DNS configuration for joltestserver.cloudapp.net (and maybe for olsenweb too) is incorrect, and causes my browser to show my own localhost. I have nothing to do with joltestserver.cloudapp.net.

Comment: I've edited my answer now that I understand better what you're asking. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your last comment until now. I do not fully understand everything, it requires more preknowledge than I have, but I do understand that I don not have to worry :-)